# php Insert Query - Why Are There Two Connections to a Database?

Tags: php, insert

In my script I link to a page that connects to my database :

include "connect.php";

**connect.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
/* Allows PHP to connect to your database */
// Database Variables
$Host = "myhost";
$User = "username";
$Password = "password";
$DBName = "database";
// Connect to Database
$connect = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password) 
or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db($DBName) 
or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());
?
```

Then in another script I have an insert query:

```
include "connect.php";

$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$Query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string($forename)."','".mysql_escape_string($surname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($username)."', '".mysql_escape_string($password)."', '".mysql_escape_string($email)."')";

        if(mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
            $message = "You have successfully registered";
            header("Location: register.php?message=".urlencode($message));
        } else {

            die("Query was: $Query. Error: ".mysql_error($Link));
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this necessary :

```
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
```

Hasn't the connection already been established?

Comment: Your `connect.php` file has `$connect` and you're using `$Link`, that doesn't add up. I for one am giving my head a shake. You shouldn't be using that, but pass `$connect` to your query instead.

Comment: Same question as mine, why is that necessary..? Any errors after you eliminate it?

Comment: The query works regardless of whether I use $Link or $connect. If I remove this statement the insert fails. what I don't understand is why is it necessary to declare it twice?

Comment: You don't need to declare it twice. Are you not "including" the file for your DB connection? @Nullbreaker That's what you should be doing, and that's why you're having that issue; most likely.

Comment: I declare the script at the top of my page. I've added the if else loop that runs after the query. I've seen this method used elsewhere, I don't understand the logic behind it as the connection has already been established.

Comment: Just remove `$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);` (*you don't need it*) and pass DB connection variable to your query. You already have an open DB connection. I.e.: change  `if(mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {` to `if(mysql_query($Query, $connect)) {`

Comment: You really should eliminate the use of mysql_* functions in favor of their mysqli_* counterparts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in doing this, especially as `mysql_*` functions will assume the last opened connection if none is given.

However, even with two calls to `mysql_connect`, *only one connection is made*. From the [docs](http://php.net/mysql-connect):

> If a second call is made to `mysql_connect()` with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The `new_link` parameter modifies this behavior and makes `mysql_connect()` always open a new link, even if `mysql_connect()` was called before with the same parameters.

So by default, the existing connection will be returned.

Comment: I've removed the first statement and all references to $Link in the if else loop. It appears to be working fine.